# SQLite still can't get foreign keys on

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I am using sqlite3.exe (sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3270200 version downloaded 2/28/2019 from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html). When I `.dump` my test database, it shows `PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;`

What am I doing wrong in my code? Note I also put `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` after opening the database, and the `.dump` still shows it as off.

**Code in:**

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
.open test1.db

CREATE TABLE META_E (E_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, E_Name TEXT, Region TEXT, Date DATE);

CREATE TABLE META_D (D_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Citation TEXT, is_used BOOLEAN);

CREATE TABLE META_G (Completion TEXT, D_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, Location TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (D_ID), FOREIGN KEY (D_ID) REFERENCES META_D (D_ID));

CREATE TABLE P_ID_Main (Source_File TEXT, P_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, E_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, D_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (P_ID, E_ID, D_ID), FOREIGN KEY (E_ID) REFERENCES META_E (E_ID), FOREIGN KEY (D_ID) REFERENCES META_D (D_ID));

.dump
```

**Dump output:**

```
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE META_E (E_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, E_Name TEXT, Region TEXT, Date DATE);
CREATE TABLE META_D (D_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Citation TEXT, is_used BOOLEAN);
CREATE TABLE META_G (Completion TEXT, D_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, Location TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (D_ID), FOREIGN KEY (D_ID) REFERENCES META_D (D_ID));
CREATE TABLE P_ID_Main (Source_File TEXT, P_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, E_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, D_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (P_ID, E_ID, D_ID), FOREIGN KEY (E_ID) REFERENCES META_E (E_ID), FOREIGN KEY (D_ID) REFERENCES META_D (D_ID));
COMMIT;
sqlite>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: That's normal, part of the standard `.dump` boilerplate. That way order of the tables and inserts doesn't matter.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks @Shawn. So the only way to check FK mapping is `PRAGMA foreign_key_list(tablename)`?

Comment: See Shawns answer. Why do you want to have `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;` ? If you really need it you can edit your dump file.

Comment: `foreign_key_list`? Huh? What are you trying to do?